# Chrome app using Tumblr OAuth: error with chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow

Tags: javascript, oauth, tumblr, google-chrome-app

I tried to perform Tumblr Authentication inside my Chrome App.

I followed [Tumblr doc](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#auth), so I registered my app using `https://my app id.chromiumapp.org/` as URL Default callback.
Tumblr API supports OAuth 1.0a Protocol so I made a POST to `https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token` to get an `oauth_token`.
I used a javascript library [(OAuth)](https://github.com/ddo/oauth-1.0a) to perform the post, in order to add all the OAuth parameters needed (`oauth_nonce`, `oauth_version`, etc).

```
var oauth = OAuth({
    consumer: {
        public: key,
        secret: secret
    },
    signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1'
});

var request_data = {
    url: 'https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
        oauth_callback: chrome.identity.getRedirectURL()
    }
};

$.ajax({
    url: request_data.url,
    type: request_data.method,
    data: oauth.authorize(request_data, {})
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data); //data contains oauth_token and oauth_token_secret
});
```

This POST succeed and I get `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret` in the response.
After that, I try to use [chrome identity API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity#method-launchWebAuthFlow) to let the user authorize my app.

```
chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(
    {
        url: "https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/authorize" + "?oauth_token=" + oauth_token, 
        interactive: true
    },
    function (responseURL) {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError){
            console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        }
        if (responseURL) {
            //everything ok
        }
    }
);
```

The call to `chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow` fails and the console shows "Authorization page could not be loaded." as `chrome.runtime.lastError.message`.
If I type `https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=my oauth_token` in the browser, I get the Tumblr authorize page.

Note that in my **`manifest.json`** file I have:

```
...
"permissions":[
    "identity",
    "https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/*", "https://api.tumblr.com/*"
]
```

but the authorization page is not loaded anyway.

I implemented the same steps for the Twitter API without errors.

I searched on StackOverflow, Tumblr documentation and Chrome API documentation, but I could not understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The documentation says that `chrome.identity.getRedirectURL` generates a redirect URL to be used in `launchWebAuthFlow` so you should use this url I guess, see: [Chrome identity launchWebAuthFlow only opens empty callback page](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30613603)

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but I'm already using `chrome.identity.getRedirectURL` URL both in code and in Tumblr app configuration page (`chrome.identity.getRedirectURL` is equal to `https://my app id.chromiumapp.org/`). Following chrome.identity doc, the url given to `launchWebAuthFlow` should be "The URL that initiates the auth flow", not the redirect one.

Comment: Sorry but the example you linked refers to a site that uses OAuth **2.0**. In that case `launchWebAuthFlow` must be called with `client_id`, `redirect_uri` and `response_type`. Tumblr unfortunately supports only OAuth **1.0a**

Comment: @VincenzoC Can you make that into an answer?

Comment: @Xan maybe my edit was misleading, but I still did not solve my issue. Probably I'm going to edit again my answer to clarify that.