# How do chromiumapp.org extension redirects work for Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

When you create a Chrome extension and want to use OAuth 2.0, you can use a `https://<app-id>.chromiumapp.org/*` URL and be therefore able to have remote servers hit your browser instance directly (answered before - for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/30613603/61239). Does anyone know, or is able to theorize on how this works? And are you able to target any request at your browser, or does this only work for OAuth 2.0?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is handled by the [`WebAuthFlow` class](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/chromium/+/master/chrome/browser/extensions/api/identity/web_auth_flow.h), whose purpose is the following:

> Given a provider URL, load the URL and perform usual web navigation until it results in redirection to a valid extension redirect URL.
>   The provider can show any UI to the user if needed before redirecting to an appropriate URL.

When the server instructs the browser to redirect to a valid extension redirect URL, that URL is instead passed to the callback function provided to `chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow`.

The 'appropriate' URLs are hardcoded in [`web_auth_flow.cc`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/chromium/+/master/chrome/browser/extensions/api/identity/web_auth_flow.cc):

```
static const char kChromeExtensionSchemeUrlPattern[] =
    "chrome-extension://%s/";
static const char kChromiumDomainRedirectUrlPattern[] =
    "https://%s.chromiumapp.org/";
```

So the special URL `https://<app-id>.chromiumapp.org/*` only works in the context of a WebAuthFlow of the `chrome.identity` API. Note that the mechanism is totally internal to Chrome. The URL is never requested.

Comment: Still, a remote server is able to contact a particular browser during the OAuth flow. My question was more about how that actually works (the mechanism through which your browser acts as a "server" for remote endpoints).

Comment: Servers never contact a browser. They only answer browser requests. One of those answers can be a redirection. When the redirection is to a `chromiumapp.org`  URL the Auth Flow is completed.

Comment: I used "server" in quotes for that reason ;) And besides, there's SSE (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events). But my point is - the OAuth server hits that `chromiumapp.org`, right? How does that translate into the browser getting the info the server sends to that URL?

Comment: No. The OAuth server tells the browser to redirect to `chromiumapp.org`. The browser instead of doing that passes the URL to the callback function you provided to ` chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow` .

Comment: Ah! That makes more sense indeed! Thanks :D

Comment: @sardaukar if you found the answer helpful you can accept it.