# Chrome Extension OAUTH with Spotify API

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, oauth

I've been writing a chrome extension using the Spotify API and just got to the part where I need OAUTH to finish it up.

I've been looking at the spotify oath page (https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/)

and it says you can just make a GET call and it'll take you to the page to log in, however when I implement it, it does nothing. I feel like I am missing some code but I am not sure what I am missing.

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    // Just alerting it to see what it came up with
    alert(xhr.responseText);
  } 
} 
xhr.open("GET", "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize/?client_id=<clientID>&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F", true);
 xhr.send();
```

that is the code I have now (with client id filled in), and running it does nothing. (I specified http://www.google.com/ as my callback for now)

Comment: 1. Where is above code? content scripts or background page? 2. Have you declared corresponding host permissions in `manifest.json`?

Comment: Yeah I have the permissions set. and the code is in content scripts

Answer (score 0):

An XHR request will not, under any circumstance, *open a page*.

Running this code should return you the page contents, but you do nothing with it - certainly not properly display it for the user to interact with.

It seems like you need to read more on OAuth in general. That said:

Chrome extension API provides a specific tool for this: [`chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity#method-launchWebAuthFlow). It will take care of showing the auth page to the user and passing the token back to you. You need to use a specific "virtual" URL for it - see the [`chrome.identity` documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity) for more details. Also note that this API can't be used in a content script, you'll need to delegate this to the background page.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but still running into an issue. Followed another SO question (that you also answered coincidentally), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30612138/chrome-identity-launchwebauthflow-only-opens-empty-callback-page,

and nothing happens when I call the script. If I set it to run everytime I click an option on a context menu, nothing happens.

Comment: Actually I fixed that, but how do I get the OAUTH token from it? Not sure how to make an API call from there